# How to recover Terraform state file

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am new to the Terraform world. I have started working on IaC for Azure using TF.

I have below three queries regarding using TF:

1. In case the state file gets accidentally deleted, is there a way to recover/recreate the state file from the current state of the Azure resources?
2. In the case of Azure, if one makes some direct changes to the Azure resources from the Azure portal, is there a way to retrofit those changes automatically into the Terraform .tf or state files?
3. Is there a way to generate terraform files for any existing Azure resources created directly from the portal?

Comment: 1. No, unless you have your own backup. 2. No, you have to manually import them. 3. Not that I am aware off (there is for aws though).

Comment: @pradeep, Did you find any solution for this . I am also looking for the same scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. In case the state file gets accidentally deleted, is there a way to recover/recreate the state file from the current state of the Azure resources?

You should configure Terraform to use a backend that saves every version of your state file, and makes it really difficult to delete the state file. If you are using Azure as the backend, then I believe that would mean enabling [Blob versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-overview), and [Soft delete for blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/soft-delete-blob-overview).

Disclaimer: I don't use Azure, so there may be more to it than that. On AWS you would enable S3 bucket versioning and MFA delete, and the features I linked appear to be the Azure equivalent.

> 2. In the case of Azure, if one makes some direct changes to the Azure resources from the Azure portal, is there a way to retrofit those
>    changes automatically into the Terraform .tf or state files?

You would need to run `terraform plan` and examine the output to see how the current Azure resources differ from the Terraform configuration, then update your Terraform configuration until `terraform plan` says there are no changes.

> 3. Is there a way to generate terraform files for any existing Azure resources created directly from the portal?

There are some tools, like `terraformer` that attempt to do this, but in my experience they are always missing support for tons of features and generally don't work well at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all rules: Is mandatory to have a regular backup of your state file! **Try to configure your Terraform backend in a remote place, like Google Cloud Storage**

Answering your questions:

1. The process of recovering a deleted state file is never easy. You should import all the resources with `terraform import`. Check this [document](https://medium.com/@abtreece/recovering-terraform-state-69c9966db71e).

2. If someone changes a resource via the Azure portal and if you do a `terraform plan` in your environment, you should check that changes were done outside Terraform. Then you should update your code to match those changes, after applying your code.
   To clarify, if someone changes your `instance_type = c4.xlarge` and you have at your code `instance_type = t3.micro`, if you apply your code, that change will be reverted so if you want to stay with instances with `c4.xlarge` you should change your code.
3. I don't use any kind of that tools but I can imagine that they exists.

Comment: You've kind of mixed and matched a lot of different things: you mention GCP first, in the second point you give an example of AWS instances. The question is about Azure though.

Comment: Since I don't use too much GCP my brain gives AWS examples  but I think that is easy to understand what I am trying to explain.

Answer (score -1):

and welcome to the `Terraform world!` Your queries address frequent Terraform infrastructure as code (IaC) scenarios.

---

> 1. In case the state file gets accidentally deleted, is there a way to
>    recover/recreate the state file from the current state of the Azure
>    resources?

---

Terraform does not offer a straight command to rebuild the state using cloud resources if the state file is accidentally deleted. Using remote state backends like **Azure Blob Storage** or **git** reduces this risk. To prevent accidental deletion and corruption, these backends can be modified with version control and state locking. If your state file is deleted, versioning lets you recover it. Without a backup or versioning, manually recreating the state file is tedious and error-prone. But importing resources into a new state file can do that. Using the `terraform import` function for each resource is laborious, especially in large regions.

###### Terraform backend example:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm={
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.60.0"
    }
  }

  backend"azurerm" {
    resource_group_name="resource-group-name"
    storage_account_name="storage-account-name"
    container_name="container-name"
    key="<file-name>.state"
  }
}
```

###### Note: For the import example, please refer to Step 1.

---

> 2. In the case of Azure, if one makes some direct changes to the Azure
>    resources from the Azure portal, is there a way to retrofit those
>    changes automatically into the Terraform .tf or state files?

---

Terraform cannot automatically detect or incorporate Azure changes mani.tf files or state. However, use the `terraform plan` tool to identify discrepancies between your Terraform configuration and Azure status. You can manually update main.tf files if changes are found. Use `terraform import` to update the state file with resources modified or added outside of Terraform if it is not in sync with the existing infrastructure.

##### Step 1: Define the Resource in Your Terraform Configuration

Start by adding the resource to your Terraform configuration file, such as main.tf. This names the Terraform resource type you want to import and gives it a reference in your project.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}
```

##### Step 2: Execute the Terraform Import Command

Add the resource to your Terraform state using the `terraform import` command. Terraform requires the Azure Resource ID, type, and name to specify a resource.

Azure Resource IDs can be found via the `Azure Portal`, `Azure CLI (az)`, or `PowerShell`. It usually resembles:

`/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}`

Use the Terraform import command by replacing {subscription-id} and {resource-group-name} with your subscription ID and resource group name.

Use the following command to import an Azure resource group into Terraform:

```bash
terraform import azurerm_resource_group.example /subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}
```

##### Step 3: Validate the Import

Use the terraform plan command to verify that Terraform matches the imported resource's configuration after importing. No changes are needed if your Terraform configuration matches the resource.

Change your Terraform setup to match the imported resource's specifications to fix any inconsistencies found by the terraform plan command. Repeat the terraform import command until no errors are found.

###### Key Points:

Using "terraform import" does not build Terraform configuration files. The Terraform state is only modified to include the resource. You must manually configure the resource before importing it.
To avoid data loss, always backup your Terraform state before importing.
To avoid inadvertent changes, make sure your Terraform setting resource definitions match the real resources before and after import.

---

> 3. Is there a way to generate terraform files for any existing Azure resources
>    created directly from the portal?

---

Terraform configurations can be generated from Azure resources using tools like `terraform import` and resource discovery tools, or scripts that generate `.tf` files. Although `terraform import` can import resources into Terraform, it can not generate configuration files. Using third-party tools and scripts like `terraformer` (not officially supported by HashiCorp) can be helpful. They can generate `.tf` and `.tfstate` files for existing resources, which Terraform can refine and maintain.

Remember, while tools can automate Terraform configuration generation, you must examine and comprehend the resulting code to verify it meets best practices and your needs.
A few examples

1. [terramate](https://terramate.io/)
2. [terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer)
3. [checkov](https://www.checkov.io/)
4. [tfsec](https://aquasecurity.github.io/tfsec/v1.28.1/)